# PHP SQL Server Connection to Local

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, local

During my internship, I'm working on a Tracking system that is based on PHP and MSSQL. The company is writing software for transport companies, also uses SQL Server databases. The next thing that I'm going to do is to get datas from those companies SQL Servers. But those SQL Servers are located in those companies local machines. Now, there's a problem that not all companies have static ip's. I'm really confused about the system, how should it go? How should the mechanism be? I may use MSSQL connection and ODBC connection (DSNless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These companies have domains right? They should create a domain-link for you to use so that you can use that url to access the sql-database. They can't expect you to build something on ip while they have a dynamic one ;-).

Comment: You're right, but I'm asking because I'm not really good at the networking stuff, that domain is actually connects to their servers, right? Of course they can't expect, they're leaving me with the problem so that I can find my answer, I've done till now, but this has been too much :)

Comment: A domain-name can be configured by them so that this name links to an ip-adress locally. F.e. myCompany.com leads to the webserver or something. They can configure f.e. sql.mycompany.com for you so you can connect via that (ofc using their domain).